# Error executing child request for pagename.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to refresh the web page. 
I am using server.execute() method to to refresh the page.

B'coz I want to execute the remaining part of the page after refreshing the page.

But I am getting the error as :

Error executing child request for /goods-inward-note/.

Here' my code.
I want as server.execute refresh the page. I want to visible the panel but control is not coming on to the same page & also giving me error.

Can any one help me why I am getting that error.

This code is on the button click.

```
Server.Execute(Request.RawUrl,false);

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
msg_pnl.Visible = true;
```

Comment: hey instead of down voting me can you tell me the appropriate way to achieve the above functionality

Comment: hey leppie I know you are expert in c#. but I am not as you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do can be achieved. As a workaround, can you try using an updatepanel to host the panel you want to manipulate and see if it works for you.

Comment: I want to refresh the page first of all that is not the big deal but after refreshing the page it  should execute the above two lines that i have mentioned above